# Jmockit code coverage and static initialization

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-coverage, jmockit

We are developing unit test for a Java App that depends on an external jar. We use JMockit, and the unit test can run successfully. Then we enable JMockit code coverage. Then the Jmockit code coverage code somehow calls into the static initialization code of a class in the external jar. Since that class is not supposed to run in a test env, this causes an exception. Note that 
1. The unit test can run successfully if code coverage is not enabled
2. The stack trace shows nothing of the class we are testing, it comes from the JMockit code (mockit.coverage.CodeCoverage.transform) to the static initialization of the third party class.
3. This is an external class in a jar, jmockit is not supposed to do code coverage about it according to the document, right? Does mockit.coverage.modification.ClassModification.modifyClassForCoverage mean instrumenting the code?
4. We tried -Djmockit-codecoverage-excludes flag, and it did not help.

Is this a bug of JMockit code coverage?

================ stack trace of error ============================

```
   at THE_THIRD_PARTY_EXTERNAL_CLASS.<clinit>(THE_THIRD_PARTY_EXTERNAL_CLASS.java:line_number)
   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
   at mockit.internal.util.ClassLoad.loadClass(ClassLoad.java:102)
   at mockit.internal.util.ClassLoad.loadClass(ClassLoad.java:54)
   at mockit.internal.util.ClassLoad.loadByInternalName(ClassLoad.java:31)
   at mockit.internal.util.ClassLoad.getSuperClass(ClassLoad.java:146)
   at mockit.internal.util.ClassLoad.actualSuperClass(ClassLoad.java:177)
   at mockit.internal.util.ClassLoad.whichIsSuperClass(ClassLoad.java:167)
   at mockit.external.asm.ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(ClassWriter.java:1694)
   at mockit.external.asm.ClassWriter.getMergedType(ClassWriter.java:1661)
   at mockit.external.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1426)
   at mockit.external.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1325)
   at mockit.external.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(MethodWriter.java:1475)
   at mockit.external.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(MethodVisitor.java:804)
   at mockit.external.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1554)
   at mockit.external.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1017)
   at mockit.external.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:693)
   at mockit.external.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
   at mockit.coverage.modification.ClassModification.modifyClassForCoverage(ClassModification.java:142)
   at mockit.coverage.modification.ClassModification.modifyClassForCoverage(ClassModification.java:217)
   at mockit.coverage.modification.ClassModification.modifyClass(ClassModification.java:192)
   at mockit.coverage.CodeCoverage.transform(CodeCoverage.java:127)
   at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
   at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:424)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1808)
   at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:38)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:65)
   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:59)
   at mockit.integration.junit4.JMockit.<init>(JMockit.java:30)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
   at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
   at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
   at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
   at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
   at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
   at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do question-specific, but it does environment-specific. I had issues with test coverage in Eclipse. I switched to IntelliJ IDEA and my problems were gone.

Comment: Sounds like a bug of Eclipse or JMockit. We can not switch to IntelliJ IDEA unfortunately.